# How to manage python packages in ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, python, pip

I am relatively new to setting up my own programming environment from scratch. I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-programming-environment-on-an-ubuntu-16-04-server) tutorial and set up a virtual machine as well as a virtual environment. When I started working on a project and installing packages (presumably on my virtual environment once I activated it), it did not take long until I was completely lost.

I don't understand how to track:

- The differences between `pip` and `pip3` (What does it mean if a package in installed for Python2 vs for Python3?)
- How to see if a package is
  actually installed locally vs globally?
- How to see if a package is
  installed for a specific user vs globally?
- What is the difference
  between virtual environment package installation vs only for a user
  vs globally?
- Etc...

Could someone either answers some of the questions above or point me to a good place to learn the basics and to learn how to properly set up package management well, so that I can build and update packages with confidence going forward.

I am running a `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS`

P.S. Maybe this questioned is asked already somewhere, but I could not find the answers.

Comment: FWIIW, this post helped me the most so far: https://www.dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/

Comment: I have asked [the similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1075843/66509) and [other](https://askubuntu.com/q/1075848/66509).

Comment: You can check to see if a command is installed locally or globally by using the `which` command. For example, `which youtube-dl`. Although, sometimes a package is installed both globally and locally and for this you can run `whereis youtube-dl` instead, to show all installed paths. Of course, If it shows a local path, it's installed locally.